# querying elastic search (like sql "having")

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a table of people and what languages they speak.
I need to get humans(hid) who knows only one language,
for test it (eng and ger)
I want to get (hid 3) and (hid 4)

```
PUT test/huml/1 
{"hid":1,"lang":"eng"}
PUT test/huml/2 
{"hid":1,"lang":"ger"}
PUT test/huml/3 
{"hid":1,"lang":"fr"}
PUT test/huml/4 
{"hid":2,"lang":"eng"}
PUT test/huml/5 
{"hid":2,"lang":"jap"}
PUT test/huml/6 
{"hid":3,"lang":"eng"}
PUT test/huml/7 
{"hid":4,"lang":"ger"}
PUT test/huml/8 
{"hid":5,"lang":"eng"}
PUT test/huml/9
{"hid":5,"lang":"ger"}
PUT test/huml/10 
{"hid":6,"lang":"eng"}
PUT test/huml/111 
{"hid":6,"lang":"jap"}
```

in oracle sql this would be done like this:

```
with
  t as (
  select 1 hid, 'eng' l from dual union all
  select 1, 'ger' from dual union all
  select 1, 'fr' from dual union all      
  select 2, 'eng' from dual union all
  select 2, 'jap' from dual union all
  select 3, 'eng' from dual union all
  select 4, 'ger' from dual union all
  select 5, 'eng' from dual union all
  select 5, 'ger' from dual union all
  select 6, 'eng' from dual union all
  select 6, 'jap' from dual 
)
 select hid,max(l)
 from t
 group by hid,l
 having count (distinct case when l  in ('eng','ger') then l end) = 1
    and count(1) =1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you're asking directly, yet (though see GitHub issues [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4404) and [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8110)). You could probably hack something together with a [scripted metric aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html), though that's not really ideal either (and I'm assuming wouldn't scale that well, though I haven't tried).

With what you posted, it's possible to find out *how many* languages users speak pretty easily:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "humans": {
            "terms": { "field": "hid" },
            "aggs": {
                "num_of_langs": {
                    "value_count": { "field": "lang" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to really be what you're asking.

If you modify your schema a bit, though, you can solve the problem (more or less) with a combination of [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) and [has_child](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-filter.html) filters. Here's one way.

I took the docs you posted, and extracted "parent" objects for each `"hid"`. I used a mapping that sets up a parent-child relationship, then bulk indexed the documents:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "human": {
         "properties": {
            "hid": { "type": "long" }
         }
      },
      "has_lang": {
         "_parent": { "type": "human" },
         "properties": {
            "hid": { "type": "long" },
            "lang": { "type": "string" }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"human", "_id":1}}
{"hid":1}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"human", "_id":2}}
{"hid":2}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"human", "_id":3}}
{"hid":3}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"human", "_id":4}}
{"hid":4}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"human", "_id":5}}
{"hid":5}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"human", "_id":6}}
{"hid":6}

PUT /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":1, "_id":1}}
{"hid":1,"lang":"eng"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":1, "_id":2}}
{"hid":1,"lang":"ger"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":1, "_id":3}}
{"hid":1,"lang":"fr"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":2, "_id":4}}
{"hid":2,"lang":"eng"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":2, "_id":5}}
{"hid":2,"lang":"jap"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":3, "_id":6}}
{"hid":3,"lang":"eng"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":4, "_id":7}}
{"hid":4,"lang":"ger"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":5, "_id":8}}
{"hid":5,"lang":"eng"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":5, "_id":9}}
{"hid":5,"lang":"ger"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":6, "_id":10}}
{"hid":6,"lang":"eng"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index", "_type":"has_lang", "_parent":6, "_id":11}}
{"hid":6,"lang":"jap"}
```

Then I can query for humans who speak a particular language, but no other, as follows:

```
POST /test_index/human/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "has_lang",
                  "filter": { "term": { "lang": "ger" } }
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not": [
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "has_lang",
                  "filter": {
                     "not": {
                        "filter": {  "term": { "lang": "ger" } }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "human",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "hid": 4
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You do still have to do this for each language, so this method is perhaps not ideal, but hopefully it will get you closer.

I also tried using aggregations to get the answer you want, but never found a way to make it work. If/when reducer aggregations get implemented, that will presumably solve this kind of problem, if I understand the idea correctly.

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/0615ec52346ae6e547988b156b221484dbfde50c

Comment: complex solution, i wanted to replace classic relational db for statistics with fast elasticsearch, but is seems hard to query data